# Having different versions of API

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, backbone.js, laravel

While looking through other people's code, I noticed that some code their javascript/backbone.js in such a way that is is easy to change the version of their serverside API.

```
API_URL = '/api/v2/';
```

**Question:** What is the purpose of being able to change the version of the API used from `v2` to `v1` or `v3` so easily but not able to change the clientside code as easily?

Here's an example of a backbone.js snippet:

```
var POST_API = '/api/v1/post/'

window.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: POST_API
})

window.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post,
    url: POST_API
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is that when the API is upgraded, services or scripts (mostly from third parties) will still be able to use the olds API.

This mean, this way of using a version name in the API url let you update your API without breaking legacy code/apps (as long the old version is still available).

Comment: I guess that if my API is only used by my site, there will be no need to do this.

Comment: Maybe not, unless you can't afford to refactor all your code at once. So, it'll mostly depends on the size of your site/app (But I think using a version number URL is way more future proof - never know what could happen).

Comment: Yeah agreed with Simon. If you were going to upgrade your API, it's easier to rollback using version numbers if something goes awry.